# Pandas Dataframe to Json using df.to_dict('records') changes a column on lists to strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a pandas dataframe to json format list of dictionaries using df.to_dict('records'). The dataframe contains a column of list of strings. When calling to_dict the list of strings are converted to a string e.g.

| key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- |
| ['a', 'b', 'c'] | x |

becomes...

```
[{"key1": "['a', 'b', 'c']", "key2": "x"}]
```

I would like the result to be

```
[{"key1": ['a', 'b', 'c'], , "key2": "x"}]
```

How do I prevent key1's value from being a sting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to loop through the list of dictionaries and change the format using ast.literal_eval()

```
import ast

#where json is a list of dictionaries

for x in json:
    x["key_of_sting_of_list"] = ast.literal_eval(x["key_of_sting_of_list"])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can convert the JSON into something like `[{"key: ['a', 'b', 'c']"}]` instead of `{"key": "['a', 'b', 'c']"}` you would be able to retain the JSON format.

```
data = ["key: ['a', 'b', 'c']"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["JSON"])
df
```

|  | JSON |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | key: ['a', 'b', 'c'] |

Please share the original JSON output so that I can help you better.